# Swagger Code Generation: models taking benefit of PHP7

Tags: php, swagger, mustache, swagger-codegen

We're using Swagger for our API specification and Swagger Code Generator to automatically generate the related models.

We're using the provided PHP models which works great but doesn't take benefit of PHP 7.1.

**I tried to find PHP 7.1 models but I could not find any nor on the official repository or others people repositories.**

1. **Do you know some places where models that take benefit of PHP7 stand?**
2. **If not, our team is willing to do them. Some of you would be interested?**

---

Current models, made for PHP5:

```
/**
  * Figure.
  */
class Figure implements ArrayAccess {
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->container['id'];
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    private function setId($id) {
        $this->container['id'] = $id;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

Models taking benefit of PHP 7 would look like:

```
/**
 * Figure.
 */
class Figure implements ArrayAccess {

    public function getId(): int {
        return $this->container['id'];
    }

    private function setId(int $id): self {
        $this->container['id'] = $id;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of response are you expecting? At the moment it seems OT because either a) You're asking for an off-site resource, b) people's personal opinion, or c) you don't actually have a programming question?

Comment: What I'm expecting: a link to a repository with PHP7 models template would be great.

Comment: That would be a) then, and thus, off-topic :).